# Set Window Popup coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using JQuery UI Dialog like this ;

```
 $(function () {
        var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 950,
            height: 480,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            minHeight: 30,
            minwidth: 30,
            title: 'test'
        });
    });
```

Window :

```
    function PopupUrl(url, name, width, height) {
        var features = "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + '"';
        window.open(url, name, features);
    }
```

Dialog was opened page's center but popup appear different coordinates. I want to overlapping. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a calculated top and left to your features list and the popup will be positioned at the center of the screen :

```
function PopupUrl(url, name, width, height) {
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight / 2) - (height / 2));
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth / 2) - (width / 2));
    var features = "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left;
    window.open(url, name, features);
}
```